# QT, running the function for specific time

Tags: c++, qt, timer

i have QT application that plays mp3.

when i call play() function, it plays the music until the mp3 ends. But, i want to play it for 2 seconds.

```
player->play();
//after 2 seconds
player->stop();
```

how can i control the time between play and stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [QTimer::singleShot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#singleShot). If your player has a slot called `stop()` use a single shot timer like this:

```
player->start();
QTimer::singleShot(2000, player, SLOT(stop()));
```